# A simple numpy reshape function in python when making 2D array from 1D array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I had a simple question involving np.reshape. I am trying to learn how to make a 2D array from 1D array using np.reshape. I watched this tutorial that does it but I still have some questions about the tutorial..

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(8*16)

frame_length = 8

a_framed = np.reshape(a, (-1, frame_length))

print (a_framed)
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is frame_length determining the number of columns in the new 2D array? If so, why not just put the number 8 in 'a_framed'? Is it not possible to do that?
2. What is '-1' in 'a_framed'? What does it do? (explanation omitted in the tutorial or not sufficient for me)

Thanks!
Cece

Comment: Looks like overkill... consider... b = np.arange(8*16).reshape(8,16) ...  notice that if you are generating arange using a produce of n*m, you can reshape if to (m,n) and compare it to reshape(n,m).  (the -1 is just replacing the first term in the reshape, by whatever number needed to make it 2D

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Can you please elaborate on what -1 does? Thank you!

Comment: in your example, np.reshape requires the array 'a' and a shape.  The shape is given as (-1, frame_length) ... since there are 2 places specified, you are reshaping to a 2D array. Now, you can only reshape an array to match the size of the input which is 8*16 = 128.  In the reshape, the 2nd term is specified as frame_length which equals 8... -1 essentially means 'whatever is needed' to keep the size of the array the same with the 2D shape... in this case... (16, 8)  the size = np.prod(a.shape).  You can change the shapes like b = np.reshape(a, (2,2,4,8)) to see other shapes for the same data

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.  You could.  It is possible, but the example is trying to show you the functionality you ask about in question 2.
2. `-1` is usually a wildcard in python.  In this case, it's `a.size/frame_length`, the other dimension needed to use all of `a`.  Change `a_framed` to 4 or 16 and it still works.  Change it to 5 and:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "", line 4, in <module>
   a_framed = np.reshape(a, (-1, frame_length))

   File ". . . fromnumeric.py", line 225, in reshape
   return reshape(newshape, order=order)

   ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
   ```

It can't fit, so numpy throws and error.